# Name Compose is not defined from Scikit-image after Cx_Freeze build

Tags: python, exe, scikit-image, cx-freeze

I am trying to build a exe via Cx_Freeze, the python scripts run without issue before build.

After the Cx_Freeze compiled and built successfully, I am having trouble loading the module cytoolz where it says NameError: name 'compose' is not found.

This error seems to be throw from the module scikit-image following the error call chain:

[image]

So far, following potential resolution similar to this error, I've tried to uninstall/reinstall cytoolz followed by a conda upgrade suggest by hafarazi (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3441). However, it's no success.

My setup.py :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
# When using flask-sqlalchemy add sqlite3.dll to include_files

import os.path
import scipy
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
print(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR)
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')


#This fix the issue where Scipy module _ni_support can't be properly imported during build.
includefiles_list=[]
scipy_path = os.path.dirname(scipy.__file__)
includefiles_list.append(scipy_path)


buildOptions = dict(
    packages = ['flask','requests','sys','Jinja2','idna','encodings', 'asyncio','numpy', 'engineio','eventlet'],
    excludes = [],
    include_files=['templates/', 'static/', scipy_path]
)

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None
# base = 'Console'

executables = [
    Executable('runserver.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='Test',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)

#After build:
#rename Jinja folder with jinja if module jinja is not found error encoutnered
```

My platform is :
Windows 10
Python 3.6

Any suggestion to a possible pathforward to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with cx_freeze, but I've run into similar issues with PyInstaller, and had to add paths to `hidden_imports`. cx_freeze might have a similar facility. See this example from CellProfiler: https://github.com/CellProfiler/distribution/blob/master/windows/CellProfiler.spec#L28

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message and your setup script as text into your post. You can format them as code blocks by indenting with 4 spaces.

Comment: Have you tried to add `scipy` and `cytoolz` to the `packages` list in `buildOptions`?

Comment: Under the folder build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib, I can see the cytoolz and scipy, do I still need to add them into buildOptions ?

Comment: I would definitely try that, yes. If I understand correctly your error message, `cytoolz` can be found in the build foolder, but parts of it (at least the function `compose`) cannot. You could also try to add `cytoolz.functoolz` (the module defining `compose`) to the `packages` list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (at least I guess), that 'compose' isn't defined properly in cytoolz\__init__.py:

```
from .itertoolz import *

from .functoolz import *

from .dicttoolz import *

from .recipes import *

from .compatibility import map, filter

# from . import sandbox

from functools import partial, reduce

sorted = sorted

# Aliases
comp = compose #<-- HERE!

# Always-curried functions
flip = functoolz.flip = curry(functoolz.flip)
memoize = functoolz.memoize = curry(functoolz.memoize)

functoolz._sigs.update_signature_registry()

from ._version import __version__, __toolz_version__
```

Someone apparently thought that it might be a good idea to use `from ... import *`.
I am working on the same problem right now and will let you know if I found a way to solve this.

EDIT: By looking through `functoolz` I found `compose`. Fixed this bug by adding (in `cytoolz\__init__.py`)

```
import functoolz as futo
```

and replacing

```
comp = compose
```

with

```
comp = futo.compose
```